# WCFBinding in DotCMIS

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, cmis, ibm-datapower, dotcmis

Am trying to invoke a CMIS repository webservice URL from a WCF service. I need to ensure that I have WCF binding (basicHttp) on invoking that webservice (to mutually exchange certificates between client and Data power). Hence i used the below code:

DotCMIS - Code Snippet:
Parameters[SessionParametet.WebServicesWCFBinding] = "myWCFServiceBindingName";

Note: "myWCFServiceBindingName" is the name of basicHttpBinding defined in the web.config related to the WCF service.

There is no error when the above code is executed but it throws the below error message when instantiating a session to perform operations on the repository.

Error Message:
No elements matching the key 'myWCFServiceBindingName' were found in the configuration element collection.

Could someone share your thoughts on this issue ?